# Turn off notification from iPhone OS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, jailbreak

I am developing an iPhone app in which I would like to get a notification whenever a user Turn off the iPhone or due to low battery iPhone OS turns off itself.

Any Private API will also work for me

Answer (score 0):

In case that the iOS is of or out of signal 
If the apple server could not deliver the push notification it will save it in queue. The only problem is that the queue has length == 1;